# Tutorial not workin on MAC or Linux

Tags: redis

When trying out this tuturial => https://redis.io/topics/encryption

I keep getting this error on my local mac and remote linux:

```
Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number (conn: fd=11)
```

The only difference is I run the command like this:

```
sudo ./src/redis-server /etc/redis/redis-6.2.6.conf
```

redis-6.2.6.conf

```
tls-cert-file /Users/dwesley/Documents/redis-6.2.6/tests/tls/redis.crt
tls-key-file /Users/dwesley/Documents/redis-6.2.6/tests/tls/redis.key
tls-ca-cert-file /Users/dwesley/Documents/redis-6.2.6/tests/tls/ca.crt
tls-dh-params-file /Users/dwesley/Documents/redis-6.2.6/tests/tls/redis.dh
tls-port 6379
tls-replication yes
tls-cluster yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The certs got corrupted some how on generation, it works with properly generated certs.

Comment: You can provide a solution to it and explain your findings a bit more so that it will help future readers. Do accept your answer!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).